# Log feignclient fallback exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, fallback, spring-cloud-feign

Fallback is a cool feature in Feignclient, however I would like to know what happens during fallback event. Is there anyway to output the root cause to log file?

Comment: What do you mean by what happens during fallback? When there is an error on the service side say non 0k http response, the fallback will be invoked. Here is the actual pr to feign which added the feature. https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/pull/308/files

Comment: eg: when the feignclient endpoint return http code 404/403, the fallback code inside fallback class execute. Traditionally I am able to program it in resttemplate with try/catch.

Comment: Yes you can do the same with try and catch, but compare it to HystrixFeign.builder().target(GitHub.class, "http://localhost:" + server.getPort(), fallback);

Comment: Its supposed to make the logic cleaner and avoids you the need to do try catch everywhere

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get it. For my case, when the target API has an exception, it simply return the result in fallback method.

Comment: yup, that's the feature, when the http call fails it will invoke the routine defined in fallback and return the response. Did you expect something else?

Comment: yeap, I would like to know why it happens. Trying to print some logs in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use the `fallbackFactory` attribute inside `@FeignClient`, which can access to the cause that made the fallback trigger.

```
@FeignClient(name = "hello", fallbackFactory = HystrixClientFallbackFactory.class)
protected interface HystrixClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello")
    Hello iFailSometimes();
}

@Component
static class HystrixClientFallbackFactory implements FallbackFactory<HystrixClient> {
    @Override
    public HystrixClient create(Throwable cause) {
        return new HystrixClient() {
            @Override
            public Hello iFailSometimes() {
                return new Hello("fallback; reason was: " + cause.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```